# Error connecting to AWS Transfer (SFTP service) via Filezilla

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, amazon-iam

I have created a server on [AWS Transfer](https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/) and I have setup everything as per the documentation.

The Policy I have created (scope down policy) is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeBucket}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${transfer:HomeFolder}/*",
                        "${transfer:HomeFolder}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectACL",
                "s3:PutObjectACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeDirectory}*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy I got from the AWS documentation itself.

I created a Role with the above policy attached and it has trust permission with the "Transfer" service.

I created the users with the Role and the policy attached

[image]

I seem to have followed all the steps as per the documentation, but I am getting a permission denied while doing a directory listing for the users home directory. I am pretty sure that I have missed something in the role or policy creation process but I have been unable to crack this for past few days. I need some help as I couldn't find anything while searching online.

Comment: Doesn't it fall under `software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
`

Comment: I do not think your question is *"unique to software development"*.